# How to pass data between task in Ruby Rake?

Tags: ruby, rake

So how to pass data between task in Ruby Rake?
Believe me I read a lot bout this in the internet and none makes sense.

I found the ENV['some_var'] approach, But I can't share objects without some conversions, unnecessary additional conversions that cost time to me and the processor :(. Additionally: "Come on, is this the best that they made up?"

Somebody said use instance or class variables. It is hacky isn't it? I mean it is semantic fiasco. The modules in Ruby are places to put methods and constants- I read somewhere, which makes sense at some some extend, but class and instance variables in modules? Why classes then?

So how can I share data between two rake tasks without doing some hacking?

For example: How to pass the response object from task `get` to task `ping_server`:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'


namespace :http_request do
    desc 'Request server to obtain status, and stores the data in the memcache specified by the environment'
    # This task is made generic so it can serve as a low level routine for other tasks.
    # Thus avoiding repetitive code.
        task :get, [:url] => [:environment] do |t, args|
            #configuration
            WAIT_RESPONSE_TO_IN_SECONDS = 5
            uri = URI.parse(args[:url])
            http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

            # We cannot wait for response forever, therefore provide timeout
            http.open_timeout = WAIT_RESPONSE_TO_IN_SECONDS # in seconds

            request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)


            # The response may take too long, or the URI may be bad(invalid)
            begin
                response = http.request(request)
                puts response.code
                ENV['req_response'] = {status: "ok", val: response.inspect}.to_s
                # Rails.cache.write(args[:name], response.code)
            rescue Exception => e
                puts "\nRequest filed: #{e}\n"
                ENV['req_response'] = {status: e.to_s, val: nil.to_s}.to_s
            end
        end

      end
namespace :server_state do

    desc "write cache"
    task :ping_server, [:url] => "http_request:get" do
        response = eval(ENV['req_response'])
        puts "\n\nRESULT = #{response}"
        puts "\n\nRESULT = #{response[:val]}"
    end

end
```

Comment: Can you post an example on what you are trying to do? Why do you have to pass data around in the first place?

Comment: I am trying to pass object of this type ( https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTPResponse.html ) from child to parent task. Each task is in different namespace.

Comment: Way easier to write your task bodies as standalone classes, and then call the functions of those classes from the rake tasks.